# Large Images Display Browser Crashing Issue

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

My Browser is crashing when i load the large image.So Please how can handle large image display in PHP. And my image size is less then 10MB. And Also my image display in slide sow 5 images.[image: This is the crashing browser image]

So How can i handle large image Display.

Comment: Did you tried to resize it??

Answer (score 0):

without seeing the code it's hard to tell, but 10mb is massive for a web image. I would reformat it to jpg or png and lower the quality to make it a much smaller size. You need to find a balance of file size and quality of image.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for support.

I solved it using resize the image.
Now My page can't crash It's working good.